# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin macOS High sierra 10.13.6

Tags: node.js, macos-high-sierra, symbol-not-found

1. Command: "**Brew install node**" after install
2. Command: "**which node**" -> output: "/usr/local/bin/node"
3. Command: "**node -v**" -> output:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
```

Hope help me as soon as possible. Thanks.

Try as above that is the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually my problem with node version. The latest version 18 of Node is build for Mac OS X 10.15. My Mac version is 10.13. I downgrade Node 18 to 16. It's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

works for me too, but I had to instal the pkg with brewe does not work

Comment: Have you try: "brew install node@16" this command?

Comment: Yes, and nothing, later I went to node site, and download the version 16 of the instalation package and works as charm