# Running NodeJS in MAC OS 10.13

Tags: node.js, macos

I'm using an old MAC OS and I didn't have any issue before, but after I reset it and installed the NodeJS and I tried the `node -v` or even `npm -v` I get this error message.

```
adnanes-MacBook-Pro:react adnaneabid$ node -v
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib.
```

Just for info, the MAC I'm using: macOS High Sierra, version 10.13.6, Model 2011 and I can't update the OS because it's too old.

Answer (score 2):

If your Mac version is below 10.14 you should install node 16 or below. The latest version 18 of Node is build for Mac OS X 10.15.
[This issue might be relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74505987/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-chkstk-darwin-macos-high/74650407#74650407)

Comment: Yes, that's what I did to solve my issue and it worked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by installing an old NodeJS version,
I'm sharing a link in case someone else is getting the same error message.

[Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69815052/symbol-not-found-chkstk-darwin)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Here is the actual link to Node JS 16.20.2:

https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.20.2/