# Lazy symbol binding failed when running a javascript file for the first time on macbook

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Ive installed vs code, node js and code runner on my mac but when i tried running a javascript file for the first time I received this error
Dyld: Lazy symbol binding failed:symbol not found:__chkstk_darwin

I tried console.log(‘hello world’). The expected output should be ‘hello world’

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74505987/18057908) might be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I installed node version 16 and it worked just fine. Thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If your Mac version is below 10.14 you should install node 16 or below. The latest version 18 of Node is build for Mac OS X 10.15.
[might be relevant issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74505987/dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-not-found-chkstk-darwin-macos-high/74650407#74650407)